# Column responsive behavior and breakdown. Display columns 2x3 vs. 1x6 on mobile (with limited HTML access)

Tags: html, css, woocommerce, responsive

I'm using the Avada Fusion Theme so I have limited access to editing the core theme HTML files.

I do however have access to Custom CSS.

I'm having trouble making the below columns display as 2x3 instead of 1x6 on mobile only under 800px media screen:

[IMAGE showing mobile view of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9p7z.jpg)

Here is the page that is displaying the issue (20th Jun 2017) be sure to switch to mobile view:

https://zeralynx.co.uk

Here is the CSS I'm using, all 6 of the columns have the same ID selector "home-product-tiles":

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
#home-product-tiles {
    width: 47% !important;
    display: inline !important;
    float: left !important;
    margin-right: 2% !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
}
```

I can't figure out why the 4th column (which is the first in the second row on desktop view) won't float to the right of the 3rd column (which is the last in the first row on desktop view).

Please help me, I'd be most grateful, I bet this is so simple to fix!

Regards,
Zach

Comment: You have `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` set for the individual tiles here ... you should rather place that on the parent fusion-row element.

Comment: You beauty thank you! Got it sorted now. I'll wrap this question up. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your columns are not equal in height. Also do not use both `display:inline` and `float:left` . They are essentially doing the same thing.

You can use `display:flex` to equal the height of the columns. See the example snippet below

```css
wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  display: inline;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<wrapper>
  <div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <h2>
Some text
</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x250">
    <h2>Some text</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x50">
    <h2>Some text</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x450">
    <h2>Some text</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <h2>Some text</h2>
  </div>
</wrapper>
```

Comment: Thank Mihai T. I've got it to work but it's something within Fusion. I will create an answer below to wrap this up. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @VisualWizardry Glad i could help. If this answer worked for you do not forget to rate/accept it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks man! I tried to rate it but I don't even have any rep yet hah! I've wrapped up this question in a new answer below.

Comment: @VisualWizardry you can accept the answer though ;) as it seems this was the solution. And please, do not use `!important` only if really really necessary

Comment: Sure thank you. I've accepted your answer. Yes thanks I'll se what !important's I can remove.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

***Thank you Mihai T and CBroe.***

I applied the below ID "home-product-tiles-wrapper" to the Avada Fusion Container that held the 6 columns, then added in the `display: flex` & `flex-wrap: wrap` as below.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
#home-product-tiles-wrapper .fusion-row {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
}
#home-product-tiles {
    width: 48% !important;
    margin-right: 2% !important;
    float: left !important;
    display: inline !important;
}
}
```

This is what it was like before which wasn't what I needed:
[SCREENSHOT BEFORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQlGf.jpg)

It now displays as I want it to like in this screenshot:
[SCREENSHOT AFTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9P7i.jpg)

Thanks again!